# WPF ListBox Header And Data Alignment

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I am trying to align data with the headers in a WPF application. The headers a line up and spaced nicely. However, I cannot get the data items underneath to line up with the headers. Any suggestions?

I have been poking around a bit, but have not found a solution to my problem. I do have to stick with list box as it is part of the requirements. Also, I am new to WPF.

Here is what the output is:
[image]

And here is the xaml that I am using:

```
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}">
                <ListBox.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="ToteNumber"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="Desription"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="Time"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Tote Number" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Description" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Time" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ItemsPresenter></ItemsPresenter>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ListBox.Template>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <StackPanel>
                            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                            </Border>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Property1}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Property2}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Property3}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: You're forgetting to set SharedSizeGroup on the ColumnDefinitions.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" on a parent panel and you need to identify the SharedSizeGroup on each column so it knows which column in your listbox template grid corresponds to which one in your itemtemplate.

Note that I think * width is treated as Auto when you apply Sharedsizegroup.
I use width auto and minwidth instead when I've done something similar.

You may find you need to bind width of each column to some parent measuring grid or calculate minwidth using a converter based on ViewportWidth of the scrollviewer in your listbox.

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="2"  Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}">
            <ListBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="A" x:Name="ToteNumber"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="B" x:Name="Desription"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="C" x:Name="Time"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Tote Number" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Description" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Time" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ItemsPresenter></ItemsPresenter>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ListBox.Template>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <StackPanel>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                        </Border>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  SharedSizeGroup="A"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  SharedSizeGroup="B"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="C"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Property1}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Property2}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Property3}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

As I mentioned, I use a similar technique in some of my own markup.  For that I put the headers grid and then the listbox with an itemtemplate in a stackpanel.

```
 <StackPanel>
      <Grid>
          Headers
      <ListBox>
          ItemTemplate
</StackPanel>
```

Sounds like that doesn't suit whatever is driving your requirements though.